# How to get file change count from Gitlab API?

Tags: gitlab

Using Gitlab commit API with the attribute 'with_stats' set as yes, I am able to get the line change additions, deletions and total but I dont see an option to get the file change count as available at :

```
git show --stat
```

or even at Gitlab UI :

[image].

With the gitlab API:

```
https://<gitlab_server>/api/v4/projects/:id/repository/commits?with_stats=yes
```

I see a response like :
"stats": {
"additions": 9,
"deletions": 2,
"total": 11
}

but nothing like { "file_changes": 1 }

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if exist a direct method for it, but you can try this below command on your terminal

`git show --format=oneline --stat COMMIT_SHA | grep "|" | wc -l`